# A* Search Algorithm Not Giving the Optimal Path

Tags: algorithm, matlab, a-star

I am trying to create a MATLAB script for A* Search Algorithm. I created a script. I tried it with a 6-node graph, and computed the correct path. However, this time I tried the script for a different graph (with 12 nodes) and this time I received a wrong answer.

These are the node information nodes.csv file:

```
Node number, (x, y) coords, heuristic cost

1,   -0.5,-0.5,         1.4142    
2,   -0.09,-0.4,        1.0762    
3,   -0.285,-0.305,     1.1244    
4,    0.0575,-0.225,    0.8494    
5,   -0.0525,-0.0175,   0.7604    
6,   -0.37,0.3,         0.8927    
7,    0.3525,-0.0525,   0.5719
8,    0.0625,0.255,     0.5014
9,   -0.1,0.3725,       0.6134
10,   0.4275,0.195,     0.3135
11,   0.345,0.3525,     0.214
12,   0.5,0.5,            0
```

These are the edge informations from edges.csv file (edges are undirected):

```
Node 1, Node 2, Cost

12,     11,   0.214
12,     10,   0.3135
12,     8,    0.5014
11,     10,   0.1778
11,     9,    0.4454
10,     7,    0.2586
9,      8,    0.2005
9,      6,    0.2796
9,      5,    0.5994
8,      4,    0.48
7,      4,    0.3417
5,      2,    0.179
4,      3,    0.3517
4,      2,    0.2289
3,      2,    0.2169
3,      1,    0.2903
2,      1,    0.422
7,      5,    0.4402
5,      4,    0.11
```

The solution to the graph is: 1 - 3 - 4 - 7 - 10 - 12.

The path my script calculated is: 1 - 3 - 4 - 2 - 5 - 5 - 7 - 10 - 12.

Notice that node 5 is shown twice, which I have no idea about. I tried to debug, but could not find what was the incorrect part.

Here is my code:

```
clc
clear
%% Constructing the Nodes with their information:
%  Assigning the adjacent node information to nodes:
nodes = readmatrix('nodes.csv');
edges = readmatrix('edges.csv');

node(1).successors = [2 3];
node(2).successors = [3 4 5];
node(3).successors = [1 2 4];
node(4).successors = [5 2 3 7 8];
node(5).successors = [4 7 2 9];
node(6).successors = 9;
node(7).successors = [5 4 10];
node(8).successors = [4 9 12];
node(9).successors = [5 6 8 11];
node(10).successors = [7 11 12];
node(11).successors = [9 10 12];
node(12).successors = [8 10 11];

%  Assigning heuristic cost values and cost numbers to nodes:
heuristics = nodes(:,4);
for i = 1 : length(nodes)
    node(i).heuristic = heuristics(i);
    node(i).order = i;
end

%  Initializing the pastCost and totalCost of the nodes:
node(1).pastCost = 0;
node(1).totalCost = node(1).pastCost + node(1). heuristic;
for i = 2 : length(nodes)
    node(i).pastCost = Inf;
    node(i).totalCost = node(i).pastCost + node(i). heuristic;
end

nodeStart = nodes(1, 1);
nodeGoal = nodes(12, 1);

%  Node start has no parent node:
node(nodeStart).parent = [];

%  Adding the first node to OPEN List
OPEN = {node(1)};

CLOSED = {};

%% Starting the A* Search Algorithm:
%  If tthe OPEN list is not empty, iterations are going to start:
while(~isempty(OPEN))
  current = OPEN{1};
  OPEN(1) = [];
  
  CLOSED{length(CLOSED) + 1} = current;
 
  %  If the current node is the goal node, algorithm is finished with
  %  success, return the path from the CLOSED List:
  if (current.order == nodeGoal)
      disp('SUCCESS!')
     
      for i = 1 : length(CLOSED)
         
          fprintf(' %d ', CLOSED{i}.order)
         
      end
      return
     
  end
 
  % Creating an array which consists of the node numbers of the closed nodes:
        for i = 1 : length(CLOSED)
        closedNodes(i) = CLOSED{i}.order;
        end
 
  % Starting searching through the adjacents/successors of the current node:      
  for i = 1 : length(current.successors)
      
      %  If the current node is not in the CLOSED List / member of the
      %  closedNodes array, calculations are going to be taking place:
      if (~ismember(current.successors(i), closedNodes))
         
          tentativePastCost = current.pastCost + edgeCost(current.order, current.successors(i), edges);
         
          if (tentativePastCost < node(current.successors(i)).pastCost)
              node(current.successors(i)).pastCost = tentativePastCost;
              node(current.successors(i)).parent = current.order;
             
             
              node(current.successors(i)).totalCost = node(current.successors(i)).pastCost + node(current.successors(i)).heuristic;
              
              %  Adding the current node to the OPEN List and then sorting
              %  the OPEN List with respect to total cost values:
             
              if(length(OPEN) == 0 || node(current.successors(i)).order ~= OPEN{length(OPEN)}.order)
              OPEN{length(OPEN) + 1} = node(current.successors(i));
              end
              [~,I] = sort(cellfun(@(s) getfield(s,"totalCost"), OPEN));
              OPEN = OPEN(I);
             
          end
         
      end
     
  end
 
end
disp('FAILURE!')
```

What is the reason my program jumps from node 4 to 2, instead of node 7?

Comment: You don’t use the `edges` matrix you read in? Why the hard-coded graph? What about the edge weights?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I could not figure a way out to use the edges directly, without assigning the adjacents to nodes, since I do not have a lot of time to turn in the assignment. I have also created a edgeCost function to find the cost/weight of two nodes. This function uses edges matrix.

Comment: My guess is that your network definition is wrong. For example, node 1 connects to 2, but 2 doesn’t connect to 1. A better graph representation is a matrix G where G(i,j) is the weight of the connection between nodes i and j. You can then ensure the matrix is symmetric. Elements with value 0 indicate no connection.

Comment: I am giving it a go right now, will update from here as soon as I get a result. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I had some other things to do. I noticed what I was doing wrong: While creating the path, I should have used the node structure I have created. I should have started from the 12th node (goal node) and then find its parent node. Then apply the same thing until I reach the first node. 

Also, your G matrix implementation is a lot more versatile and easier to manipulate. Thank you so much!